# Implementing cartesian product, such that it can skip iterations

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I want to implement a function which will return cartesian product of set, repeated given number. For example

```
input: {a, b}, 2
output:
aa
ab
bb
ba

input: {a, b}, 3
aaa
aab
aba
baa
bab
bba
bbb
```

However the only way I can implement it is firstly doing cartesion product for 2 sets("ab", "ab), then from the output of the set, add the same set. Here is pseudo-code:

```
function product(A, B):
    result = []
    for i in A:
        for j in B:
            result.append([i,j])
    return result
function product1(chars, count):
    result = product(chars, chars)
    for i in range(2, count):
        result = product(result, chars)
    return result
```

What I want is to start computing directly the last set, without computing all of the sets before it. Is this possible, also a solution which will give me similar result, but it isn't cartesian product is acceptable.
I don't have problem reading most of the general purpose programming languages, so if you need to post code you can do it in any language you fell comfortable with.

Comment: What's the problem with what you already have?

Comment: I want to skip iterations, since the algorithm above is working with the previous set, so if I want to generate {a,b} 8, first the pc must compute {a,b} x {a,b} then ({a,b} x {a,b})x{a,b}  ... till 8

Comment: Are you actually trying to solve a problem (real bottleneck?) or simply "optimizing for fun"?

Comment: Does solving the problem for fun count? It will help me a lot with other project, but it isn't necessary. Also I'm not sure if this problem is already solved, I mean solving it my be not possible for me

Comment: It's (sometimes) OK to look for optimizations"for fun", but I always like to remind people to [read this first](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: As i've said this is going to give me boost in other project, althought I would manage to do it with the first implementation it's going to save a lot of CPU cycles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recursive algorithm that builds S^n without building S^(n-1) "first". Imagine an infinite k-ary tree where |S| = k. Label with the elements of S each of the edges connecting any parent to its k children. An element of S^m can be thought of as any path of length m from the root. The set S^m, in that way of thinking, is the set of all such paths. Now the problem of finding S^n is a problem of enumerating all paths of length n - and we can name a path by considering the sequence of edge labels from beginning to end. We want to directly generate S^n without first enumerating all of S^(n-1), so a depth-first search modified to find all nodes at depth n seems appropriate. This is essentially how the below algorithm works:

```
// collection to hold generated output
members = []

// recursive function to explore product space
Products(set[1...n], length, current[1...m])

    // if the product we're working on is of the
    // desired length then record it and return
    if m = length then
        members.append(current)
        return

    // otherwise we add each possible value to the end
    // and generate all products of the desired length
    // with the new vector as a prefix
    for i = 1 to n do
        current.addLast(set[i])
        Products(set, length, current)
        currents.removeLast()

// reset the result collection and request the set be generated
members = []
Products([a, b], 3, [])
```

Now, a breadth-first approach is no less efficient than a depth-first one, and if you think about it would be no different from exactly what you're already doing. Indeed, and approach that generates S^n must necessarily generate S^(n-1) at least once, since that can be found in a solution to S^n.

Comment: I implemented this in python, and the result seems to be list containing empty list. what bothers me more is the fact that I don't understand how is this skipping iterations.
Here is my python code: http://pastebin.com/i8TvPJEw

Comment: @DeyanGeorgiev In the pseudocode it's pretty clear to see that nothing can be added to members unless its length is three. So if it contains the empty list Python is doing something semantically not implied by the pseudocode. My money is on it passing the lists by reference rather than by value and assigning references rather than values. Can you tell what's going on in the debugger? If it's the object thing just always pass a copy of current to Products.

Comment: I fixed the code, I need to copy "current", since current.pop, is removing its elements. However I still don't understand the algorithm

Comment: @DeyanGeorgiev Adding some discussion.